# how to manipulate dictionary of lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How to complete the blanks to get the output:

```
red shirt
blue shirt 
white shirt
blue jeans
black jeans
```

Code:

```
wardrobe = {"shirt":["red","blue","white"], "jeans":["blue","black"]}
for __:
    for __:
        print("{} {}".format(__))
```

Comment: I've updated the question reflect the output you are seeking.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! :) Is this a homework question? Have you attempted any solutions? Are you stuck with understanding some specifics, or do you simply want someone to provide you the whole solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for key in wardrobe:
    for color in wardrobe[key]:
        print("{} {}".format(color, key))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
wardrobe = {"shirt": ["red", "blue", "white"],
            "jeans": ["blue", "black"]}
for item, colors in wardrobe.items():
    for color in colors:
        print("{} {}".format(color, item))
```